# i need pass a value with TouchableOpacity in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need change the info with press the flatlist item and show in principal View
My principal problem is change the info with the touchableOpacity

```
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const actualNoticia = data[2];

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=mx&apiKey=7b1bcdb1cbe04f709b69c0ef4f9c323b')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.articles))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={styles.itemHorizontal}>
      <View style={{ flex: .9, width: windowWidth * .95, padding: 10, backgroundColor: Colors.ColorPrincipal, borderRadius: 5, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: .4 }}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.urlToImage }} resizeMode='cover' style={{ width: '90%', height: '95%' }} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: .6, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <View style={{ flex: .35 }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:12,color:Colors.ColorSecundario}}>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: .65, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:10,color:Colors.ColorSecundario}}>{item.description}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

i need change the value of actualNoticia for the item with the function onPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `useState` like this

```
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [actualNoticia, setActualNoticia] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=mx&apiKey=7b1bcdb1cbe04f709b69c0ef4f9c323b')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.articles))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{setActualNoticia(item)}}>
    <View style={styles.itemHorizontal}>
      <View style={{ flex: .9, width: windowWidth * .95, padding: 10, backgroundColor: Colors.ColorPrincipal, borderRadius: 5, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: .4 }}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.urlToImage }} resizeMode='cover' style={{ width: '90%', height: '95%' }} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: .6, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <View style={{ flex: .35 }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:12,color:Colors.ColorSecundario}}>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: .65, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:10,color:Colors.ColorSecundario}}>{item.description}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

Comment: Thansk for the help :)